# Spherical Waves-Strength at close distances

Tags: waves

If the amplitude dies off as the radius squared, what happens in areas very close to the source? It would have nearly infinite strength. How is this treated?

Comment: Do you have a particular source of the wave in mind? The answer for an explosive is probably different than light...

Comment: I was just thinking some spherical light source. Like, a light bulb?

Comment: Tony, I have added an electrostatics example below to see whether that helps you.

Answer (score 1):

The closest analogy that is readily talked about in spherical wave terms is an antenna.

To analyse the problem fully, you would need to solve Maxwell's equations in several, distict regions of space. The spherical wave is a often a good model in the homogeneous space outside the antenna's hardware. Often this is good enough to tell you what you want - e.g. received power or electric / magnetic fields in terms of the antenna's output power. The spherical waves are theoretically output by infinitely small / thin currents and charge distributions.

However, if you want to know in detail what is going on in the antenna's hardware, you'll have to solve Maxwell's equations inside the conducting hardware and match this separate solution through standard boundary conditions to the superposition of spherical waves in the free space outside the antenna. Inside the hardware, you have moving currents spread over nonzero volumes, so you don't get the divergences that you otherwise would if you assumed the spherical wave solution applied everywhere.

In other words - you leave off the spherical wave model before it diverges and shift to a fuller model of the antenna's hardware.

The simplest way to see all this in action is an electrostatics problem: calculate the electric field of a spherical charged ball wherein the charge is uniformly spread. This is a spherically symmetric problem, so clearly the electric field is everywhere radial. We can most readily apply Gauss's law for electricity over spherical surfaces concentric with the charged ball. Suppose that this spread charge is $Q$.

So let's begin with a surface of radius $r$ where $r > R$, where $R$ is the charged ball's radius. The electric field, by symmetry, is normal to the surface everywhere, and of constant magnitude $E(r)$ (where $E(r)$ is to be calculated) on the surface. The surface's area is $4\pi r^2$ So the flux of the electric field through the sphere is:

$\oint \mathbf{E} . \hat{\mathbf{n}}\, dS = 4\pi r^2 E(r)$

Gauss's law says:

$\oint \mathbf{E} . \hat{\mathbf{n}}\, dS = \frac{q}{\epsilon_0}$

where $q(r)$ is the charge inside the sphere. But, because $r > R$, $q(r) = Q$ is constant. So, outside the charged sphere we get:

$4\pi r^2 E(r) = \frac{Q}{\epsilon_0}$ i.e. $E(r) = \frac{Q}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 r^2}$

which is the "divergent" behavior you're worried about. Moreover, note that this is exactly the **same** expression holding for a point charge (outside the sphere, we can't tell how big the sphere is from electrostatic measurements alone).

However, in the second case, let's put our sphere of radius $r$ *inside* the charged ball. Now, the charge inside the sphere depends on $r$: if $Q$ is spread evenly over volume, the fraction of charge enclosed by the sphere scales like $r^3$ (since this is how volume scales). So, if we do the above Gauss's law calculation again we get:

$\oint \mathbf{E} . \hat{\mathbf{n}}\, dS = 4\pi r^2 E(r) = \frac{r^3}{R^3} Q$

i.e.

$E(r) = \frac{Q}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 R^2} r$

So the divergence has vanished!! ($R$ is a constant, the charged sphere's radius). So the field as a function of all $r$ looks like the Mathematica-drawn plot below. The principles for the dynamic situation of antennas are exactly the same: the currents driving the fields are not true threads but are spread out.

[image: Electric Field Plot]

Comment: But I mean, if you just had a perfectly spherical point source of E&M waves, or at least something that only had a radius of half a meter, the 1/(r^2) would suggest the field gets larger. With static fields this is the case, but I feel that with E&M waves I'm missing something. I know for an antenna you'd have to dig in deeper, but I'm just wondering what happens to the radius term at small radii. I feel like it can't be right.

Comment: Right, the field does indeed get very big near some antennas - say half a metre away from a source whose wavelength is hundreds of metres but whose physical size is much less than this. And the would-be divergences in the near field can be very swift indeed - for example the mth order spherical Bessel function diverges like r^{-(m+1)} in the near field: m = 1 for dipole fields, 2 for quadrupole fields and so forth. Outside a very small antenna, the currents and charges can seem like points and threads of zero extent and radius.

Comment: But once you get inside the antenna hardware, this is no longer a good model of your geometry - so you're forced to leave off the divergent model before it diverges. This is like static field outside a charged sphere where the sphere has uniform charge density. Outside the sphere, the point source model is exact. But once you get inside the sphere, things are different. You don't get $\frac{1}{r^2}$ divergence; instead the field inside the sphere varies in proportion to $r$. Am I missing something? The difference in the time varying case is you can't have monopole fields (hairy ball theorem).

Comment: @Tony If I sketched out how to do a detailed solution for the Hertzian dipole antenna so you can see how the seeming "divergences" don't happen, would this help you? Or am I missing the point of your question?

Comment: I think my problem was that we have an 'amplitude' that gets divided by r, but this amplitude is the wave amplitude at r=1, which seemed arbitrary to me.

Comment: @Tony Well, you choose the amplitude at $r=1$ so that the field matches your boundary conditions. Maxwell's equations are linear, so you can scale any solution arbitrarily and still have a perfectly good solution.

Comment: What do you mean 'so that the field matches' my boundary conditions? I have yet to really manipulate Maxwell's equations and I've only had a lower div linear algebra course.

Comment: @Tony, I'll show you a fully worked boundary value problem to see whether it might shed some light on your problem. I can't do it right now, but shall do so in the next few days.

Answer (score 1):

> I was just thinking some spherical light source. Like, a light bulb? –  Anthony Jul 22 '13 at 3:32

For a light bulb there cannot be infinite strength because the power is given by I*V and the bulb has resistance, so the current is limited. The resistance that is heated to give off light will not be giving off light at r=0, for whatever topology you might think.

In any case, the 1/r^2 behavior is valid at distances larger than the size of the source giving off light, and is modified near the boundaries where the light is produced.